# Cannot register a new user account in Jabberd by XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I have tried some code for new user registration using XMPPFrameWork in IOS.

```
(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)
error{ 
NSLog(@"Sorry the registration is failed");
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

Here is the error trace:

```
 XmppDemo[314:26961] Did not authenticate 2015-12-03 08:54:30.331 
 XmppDemo[314:26961] Sorry the registration is failed 2015-12-03 08:54:30.332 
 XmppDemo[314:26961] error: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="azlnx001" type="error">
                  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
                    <username>26</username>
                    <password>123</password>
                  </quer??y>
                  <error code="403" type="auth">
                    <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></forbidden>
                  </error>
                </iq>
```

Related:

```
(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate: 
    (NSXMLElement *)error; { 
      NSLog(@"Did not authenticate"); NSError * err = nil; 
      if ( [self.xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration]) 
        { if(![self.xmppStream registerWithPassword:@"123" error:&err]) 
          { NSLog(@"Error registering: %@", err); } 
        } 
      }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not use comments to add information to or otherwise improve your question.  Please edit it instead.   I have done the edits this time, bit you should revise them to make your question clearer.

Comment: you teach me so much, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, user registration is not enabled. You can enable `mod_register` if you wish to, as described in ejabberd documentation: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modregister

Note that it could open a spam risk as it will thus be to automate account creation.

Comment: ejabberd.yml     
access:
user:
  max_user_sessions:
    all: 10
  register:
    all: allow
    registration_timeout: infinity
  register_from:
    allow: all

Comment: How to enable mod_register?

Comment: ejabberd.yml:             ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ip_access: trusted_network         disable this: ##ip_access:trusted_network.      i can register new user with XMPPFramework in iOS client.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd.yml

```
##
## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
##
 ip_access: trusted_network
```

What is trusted_network? i don't know to configure trusted_network, so i disable it:

```
##
## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
##
## ip_access: trusted_network
```

my app can register new user. very good.